# Make newtxtext and newtxmath look Times New Roman upright

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath, newtx

Am actually using **Times New Roman unicode set from windows Character Map** then copy and paste symbols to Adobe After effects Text Layer to setup equation, and this is time consuming process. As i already have equations in a Microsoft word 2016 document, i started experimenting by converting Microsoft Word equation to Latex Code using inbuit feature and made a latex document using amsmath package and run it using **pdfLatex** and **pdftops** to generate an eps file which will open in Adobe illustrator as editable text and curved symbols. Also, As am using MikTex portable, I copied entire fonts folder from **MikTex\install\fonts** to **%appdata%\Roaming\Adobe\Fonts** to resolve missing fonts in Adobe illustrator when i open this eps file. Everything works great!

**Problem**

As i used amsmath package the math symbols fonts doesn't look Times New Roman. I want it look like Times New Roman unicode characters and upright.
So, google search told me to use **\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}** and these fonts look good but everything is italic and not upright.

I need a global solution where newtxtext,newtxmath packages look upright without tweaking Latex code generated from Microsoft word.

or

Any Other solution where eps file generated from pdflatex looks Times New Roman unicode and upright.

**Latex Document Used**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{5}{5}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
$\varepsilon_{eq}=\left[\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon_1}{R_1}+\dfrac{\varepsilon_1} 
{R_1}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}}\right]$
\end{document}
```

**Terminal Command**

```
pdflatex "myLdoc.tex"
pdftops -eps "myLdoc.pdf"
```

**pdflatex Output**

[image]

**Required output**

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the italic font is more appriopriate for variables :-)

Comment: Your required output showed all math are in roman font? Is the one you expected?

Comment: Yep Required output should look like the one in last image attached. No Italics and it should be Times New Roman Upright fonts.

Comment: So far as I know, some French and even more German would like to set the variables to be the upshape.

Comment: Hi all to Latex Experts. Any Solution for above problem?